# Add exclusion zone on highchart contour charts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Is there any chance to add exclusion zone on highcharts.[image]

In this image green marked area is exclusion zone

Answer (score 1):

By using Highcharts.SVGRenderer, you can add any shape to the chart:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            this.zone = this.renderer.path(['M', 100, 100, 'L', 150, 150, 'L', 450, 200, 'L', 450, 100, 'z'])
                .attr({
                    stroke: 'red',
                    fill: '#666666',
                    'stroke-width': 2
                })
                .add();

            this.zone.toFront()
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfue2ab4/